Finite index subgroups of a principal congruence subgroup
My question is rather straightforward.

Do torsion free principal congruence subgroups of $SL(2;\mathbb{Z}[i])$ admit proper finite index subgroups?

In particular, I am interested in the principal congruence subgroup $\Gamma$ of level $(2+i)$, as it is the fundamental group of a compact smooth hyperbolic $3$-manifold.

I am not sure I understand theis question. Isn't the principal congruence subgroup of level $(2+i) n$ a finite index subgroup of the principal congruence subgroup of level $(2+i)$ for any $n\in \mathbb Z[i]$?

@WillSawin Yes, you are right! I have been clearly overthinking it. If I may ask, by choosing $n$ in $\mathbb{Z}[I]$, is there a formula for the index?

Sure, it should be $|n|^6 \prod_{ \substack{ p \mid n\p \neq (2+i)}} (1- |p|^{-4})$ where the absolute value is the complex absolute value (so if you use the norm you divide the exponents by $2$) and the product is over prime ideals of $\mathbb Z[i]$ dividing $n$.

@willsawin Thank you again!

A classical theorem of Malcev says that finitely generated linear groups are residually finite, so groups of matrices like this have many finite index subgroups.

Every group is a finite index subgroup of itself. But maybe you mean "proper finite index subgroup".

Of course Malcev's theorem does the job, but the proof of Malcev's theorem mostly consists of reducing to the case of groups of this kind and use congruence subgroups. For instance, $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}[i])$ embeds in the product of finite groups $\prod_p\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbf{Z}[i]/p\mathbf{Z}[i])$.
